# Where does spark store state for persist?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to understand what state [Dataset#persist](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#persist--) is mutating within spark. I originally thought that I should be using the return value for the next action, however; it appears this is a reference to the same instance instead and the state is actually mutated within the same `Dataset`.

Does this mean that spark is actually mutating the state of the dataset? That said, does it mean the dataset is not purely functional in that it holds mutable state? Or, is this somehow tied to the session? And if so, again; functionally this means the dataset still contains mutable state even if it's by proxy.

```
scala> var x = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3)).toDS
x: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]

scala> x.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#25]
+- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#24]

scala> var y = x.persist();
y: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]

scala> y.explain();
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) InMemoryTableScan [value#25]
   +- InMemoryRelation [value#25], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
         +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#25]
            +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#24]

scala> x.explain();
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) InMemoryTableScan [value#25]
   +- InMemoryRelation [value#25], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
         +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#25]
            +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#24]

scala> y.unpersist();
res6: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int] = [value: int]

scala> x.explain();
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#25]
+- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#24]

scala> y.explain();
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#25]
+- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#24]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that spark is actually mutating the state of the dataset? That said, does it mean the dataset is not purely functional in that it holds mutable state?

No

> Or, is this somehow tied to the session?

Yes. Specifically it uses session's `SharedState` and its `CacheManager`.

> functionally this means the dataset still contains mutable state even if it's by proxy.

By all means. Immutability in Spark is a pragmatic decision not dogmatic and this behavior is more a rule than exception.

Comment: Thanks for this. It was my curiosity needing itching. I had just assumed since the api returned another dataset that the method was purely functional. I rather embarrassingly and incorrectly tried telling this to a colleague.